# Find the rational solution of the equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the rational solution of the equation:

$\frac{2x - 1}{2016} + \frac{2x - 3}{2014} + \frac{2x - 5}{2012}+ ...+ \frac{2x - 2011}{6} +\frac{2x - 2013}{4} + \frac{2x - 2015}{2} =\\ \frac{2x - 2016}{1} + \frac{2x - 2014}{3} + \frac{2x - 2012}{5}+ ...+ \frac{2x - 6}{2011} + \frac{2x - 4}{2013} + \frac{2x - 2}{2015}$

The problem is from a competition for seven graders. I tried various algebraic manipulations for no avail. Any hint will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Which algebraic manipulations did you try?

Comment: Please edit the question to include additional context. Which competition is the problem from? Is there any other interest or motivation? What manipulations have you attempted? Additional advice on how to write a good question is at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: This makes for a nice contest problem for I can't see anyone working this out under contest conditions (no calculators or better) *without* coming up with a trick (such as those shown in the answers though neither answerer addressed uniqueness). Therefore my gut feeling is that additional context doesn't really help other than that a link to a contest website would be nice (even if only in your native language). If only to make sure that the contest is over.

Comment: Having said that, it is well established in our meta discussions that my tendency to exempt contest questions from our usual quality criteria is not nearly universally supported (I may well be in a minority here). Therefore I will leave the low quality flag on this post open. Just recording my opinion here (for my fellow mods to see, and for anyone so inclined to comment).

Comment: Sorry there is no web site for the contest. Her is a link with the whole problems set: https://static.olimpiade.ro/uploads/attach_data/52/47/7//2016_matematica_locala_prahova_clasa_a_viia_subiecte.pdf

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen 1 degree equation, isn't it???

Comment: @TakahiroWaki Absolutely! Unless the coefficient of $x$ happens to vanish in the end (when the equation is true for all $x$ or always false). But your calculation actually implies that, which is why I upvoted you (and also because you didn't use WA). May be I'm splitting hairs, but I wanted to see solutions a 7th grader could in theory come up with. The fact that I'm part of a group organizing local (=much smaller population base than this Romanian one) contests may be related :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen It's obviously positive, such a strange problem must be never appeared on every contest.

Comment: Well, it would be a trick question (and some Romanian contestants would notice that anyway if that were the case).

Answer (score 1):

Every term is $\dfrac{2x-2k}{2015-2k+2}-\dfrac{2x-(2k-1)}{2016-2k+2}=\dfrac{2x-2017}{(2016-2k+2)(2015-2k+2)}$

Answer (score 0):

[Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B(2x-2i%2B1)%2F(2018-2i),%7Bi,1,1008%7D%5D%3DSum%5B(2x-2i)%2F(2018-2i-1),%7Bi,1,1008%7D%5D) gives $x=\frac {2017}2$.  With that value all the fractions become $1$ so each side sums to $1008$